# stop(); undefined method in as3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

i want to move to the next frame after clicking a specific button. tried putting stop(); method but it says error and the result is just alternating the 2 frames .

here's my code.

```
    //the error says call to a possibly undefined method stop.
    //i'm using adobe flash cc.
    stop();
    public function main ():void {
        enter_button.buttonMode = true;
        enter_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, checkForm);

        player.text = "";
    }
    public function checkForm (event:MouseEvent):void {
        if (player.text != ""){
            gotoAndStop(1);
            sendForm();

        }
        else{
            player.text = "please enter your name";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What class are you extending?

Comment: If this is within a class, `stop` should be inside a function (possibly `constructor` method).

Answer (score 1):

Try `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1);` - assuming you're trying to change frames on the main timeline and not an object.

Also, it's not clear where you're using this code, (on the timeline, in a class, or in the main .as) but `stop();` should be placed in the actions panel of every frame of the timeline / movieClip.